# Word Mirrored Margin - Outside margins wider than inside - opposite of settings

Tags: microsoft-word

I have set my margins for mirrored pages as it is a book but the margins settings don't work on the pages. I have set the inside margins to be wider than the outside but on the document the outside margins are wider than the inside and I don't know how to solve this problem because I have set the margins correctly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

### This is how it is supposed to be.

Page 1 is a right-hand page. Page 2 is a left hand page.

Imagine you are binding a book or putting in a loose-leaf binder. You want the wider margin on the side that will be bound.

When you view on screen, you see the opposite. The 2-page view in print preview or in print view has odd pages on the left and even pages on the right, putting page 1 on the left. It will print correctly.